# I want to delay my future builder as a i await for a network call

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a home widget with a pageview in the body of its scaffold. Inside said pageview i have two widgets, the first widget is a dashboard of some sort (i.e it displays data) the second widget is a settings menu.

```
                  Expanded(
                    child: PageView(
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      controller: _pageController,
                      onPageChanged: (index) {
                        setState(() => _selectedIndex = index);
                      },
                      children: <Widget>[
                        DashWidget(imei: dev_imei,token: _token,),
                        Menu()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

My dash widget takes the parameters indicated and uses them to perform a network call. Its build method takes a future builder, where the future is the result of the asynchronous network call. In my case, i get a snapshot error because the widget builds before any data is returned,

This is my error

```
I/flutter (  942): Snapshot Error: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'length' was called on null.
I/flutter (  942): Receiver: null
I/flutter (  942): Tried calling: length
```

If i rebuild the widget again, the network call is successful and all data is returned
This is my dashboard widget

```
class DashWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  final String token;
  final String imei;

  DashWidget({Key key, @required this.token, this.imei}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashWidgetState createState() => _DashWidgetState();
}

class _DashWidgetState extends State<DashWidget> {

  User user;
  var loanMaximum;

    static String dashUrl = "https://hapoloans.com/api/v1/loans/hapo_dash/";
    Future<ServerResponse> _getDash(String imei, String token) async {
      //HTTP Request
        var response = await http.post(
            dashUrl,
            headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
              "Authorization":"Token $token"},
            body: {"imei":imei}
        );
        //Check if response is true
        int statusCode = response.statusCode;
        //Show the status code
        print('Status Code: $statusCode');
        //Show the response body
        print('Response Body: ${response.body}');
        //Parse response into serverResponse object
        var serverResponse = response.body;
        //Convert response json to serverResponse object
        final cleanResponse = serverResponseFromJson(serverResponse);

        if (statusCode == 200) {
          return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1))
              .then((value) => cleanResponse).catchError((error) => print('Future Error: $error'));
        }
        return null;
    }

  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _getDash(widget.imei, widget.token);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getDash(widget.imei, widget.token),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<ServerResponse> snapshot) {
        //print('${snapshot.data}');
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          print('Snapshot Error: ${snapshot.error.toString()}');
          return Center(
              child: SpinKitFadingCube(
                color: Colors.greenAccent[700],
                size: 200.0,
              ));
        }
        switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
          case ConnectionState.done:
            if (snapshot.data.status == true) {
              if (snapshot.data.dashCode == "dash_1"){
                return Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                  child: SingleChildScrollView(
                    physics: AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10,
                        ),
                        Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                          ),
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.lightBlue[400],
                                    Colors.greenAccent[400]
                                  ],
                                  stops: [
                                    0,1.0
                                  ]),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Loan Balance as at',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data.balAsAt}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 10,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'KES ${snapshot.data.bal}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 40,
                                        wordSpacing: 2,
                                        letterSpacing: 1.2
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),),
                        ),
                        Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                          ),
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.lightBlue[400],
                                    Colors.greenAccent[400]
                                  ],
                                  stops: [
                                    0,1.0
                                  ]),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'You have repaid',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'KES ${snapshot.data.totalRepaid}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontSize: 40,
                                          wordSpacing: 2,
                                          letterSpacing: 1.2
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'You have',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceAround,
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Text(
                                      '1',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 18
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    CupertinoSlider(
                                        activeColor: Colors.white,
                                        max: 61,
                                        min: 1,
                                        value: snapshot.data.daysToComplete.toDouble(),
                                        onChanged: null),
                                    Text(
                                      '61',
                                      style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
                                              color: Colors.white,
                                              fontSize: 18
                                          )
                                      ),
                                    )
                                  ],
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  'Days',
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                )
                              ],
                            ),),
                        ),
                        Card(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                          ),
                          child: AnimatedContainer(
                            duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                            curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                              gradient: LinearGradient(
                                  tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                                  begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                  colors: [
                                    Colors.lightBlue[400],
                                    Colors.greenAccent[400]
                                  ],
                                  stops: [
                                    0,1.0
                                  ]),
                            ),
                            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  'Next Repayment date',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  '${snapshot.data.nextRepayPeriod}',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white,
                                        fontSize: 24,
                                      )
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),),
                        ),
                        Center(
                          child: Card(
                            elevation: 50,
                            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50)
                            ),
                            child: InkWell(
                              splashColor: Colors.blue,
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(48),
                              onTap: () {
                                print('I want to pay');
                              },
                              child: Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50),
                                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                                        tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                                        colors: [
                                          Colors.lightBlue[100],
                                          Colors.greenAccent[100]
                                        ],
                                        stops: [
                                          0,1.0
                                        ])
                                ),
                                width: 100,
                                height: 100,
                                child: Center(
                                  child: Column(
                                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Text(
                                        'Pay',
                                        style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                        ),),
                                      SizedBox(height: 5,),
                                      Icon(
                                        Icons.sentiment_satisfied,
                                        size: 25,
                                        color: Colors.black,
                                      )
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }
            else if (snapshot.data.status == false){
              return Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 10),
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                    Card(
                      margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16)
                      ),
                      child: AnimatedContainer(
                        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
                        curve: Curves.easeInOut,
                        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
                          gradient: LinearGradient(
                              tileMode: TileMode.clamp,
                              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                              colors: [
                                Colors.lightBlue[400],
                                Colors.greenAccent[400]
                              ],
                              stops: [
                                0,1.0
                              ]),
                        ),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5, vertical: 5),
                        child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Text(
                              '${snapshot.data.detail}',
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                              style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                    color: Colors.white,
                                    fontSize: 24,
                                  )
                              ),
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 20,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.sentiment_neutral,
                              size: 50,
                              color: Colors.white,
                            )
                          ],
                        ),),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(
                      height: 20,
                    ),
                    Expanded(
                        child: Container(
                          child: Center(
                            child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '1% facility fee charged daily\non reducing balance.',
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                                  style: GoogleFonts.quicksand(
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                                      )
                                  ),),
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 20,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ))
                  ],
                ),
              );
            }
            else {
              return Text('There is an error loading data: ${snapshot.error}');
            }
            break;
          case ConnectionState.active:
            return Icon(Icons.favorite_border);
            break;
          case ConnectionState.waiting:
            return Center(
                child: SpinKitFadingCube(
                  color: Colors.greenAccent[700],
                  size: 200.0,
                ));
            break;
          case ConnectionState.none:
            return Text('There is no data');
            break;
        }
        return Center(
            child: SpinKitFadingCube(
              color: Colors.greenAccent[700],
              size: 200.0,
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Can anyone please help me on how to wait for the data to come back and then build the widgets

Comment: why you are calling the _dash two times? both in initState method and build method??

Comment: build methods should always return a widget as it's return type, you can't block that. What you can do is, you can show a loading widget until the future completes, and yes, that is what you are already doing, and it is fine. Any other issues you are facing??

Comment: @Darish I was thinking the problem is because data was not being loaded in the init state, i have since removed the init state call

Comment: @Darish Well the issue i am facing is that the snapshot.hasError is always executing, even though i have no error, as a result the return value of snapshot.haserror will always be returned

Comment: why you are receiving error always? is it related to your API configuration issue? Are you facing any other issue? if not, I may post this as an answer and you can up vote and mark it as accepted.

Comment: A) Don't mix `async/await` and `Future.then`, and don't explicitly return futures from an `async` method. It makes for code that is hard to fully understand and can easily cause subtle bugs. B) Why are you artificially delaying your network call with `Future.delayed` in the first place? That seems incredibly arbitrary and is a strong indicator of code smell.

Comment: @Darish the API works well on postman. The issue is the very first build of the page, the snapshot is always an error, then on refreshing the page, the snapshot has the data i need

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct way to use a FutureBuilder

Initialize the future in the initState, this prevents future builds

```
Future _getDash;
@override
void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    _getDash = _getDash(widget.imei, widget.token);
}

...
FutureBuilder(
  future: _getDash,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
   ** Implement a switch case based on snapshot.connectionState **
  }
);
```